# Mockito: check if internet connection exists

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mockito

I'm unit testing a service class A, which is loading data from a class B. They're set up like this:

```
public class A {

    private B b;

    public A (B b)
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getInfo() throws IOException {
        return b.getData()
    }

}

public class B {

    public String getData() throws IOException {
        //gets data from the internet
        //throws IOException if it can't connect to the internet
    }   

}
```

So basically I decided to mock it like this in my setUp method

```
private static A a;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    B b = mock(B.class);
    when(b.getData()).then(invocation -> {
        try {
        final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
      }
      //some other operations follow after this, but they all work
      return "...";
    });
    this.a = new A(b);
}
```

The tests call A's getInfo() method. Whenever I disconnect my router (and run the test afterwards), it should throw an exception (it does when I try it outside the mock, anyway). However, when mocking, it never enters the exception block - it just passes the openConnection() call like there's no problem. Why could that be?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection() appears to indicate that it doesnt actually open a connection, just wires one up.

Comment: A unit test should not depend on the state of your internet connection. The point of Mockito is to allow you to remove such dependencies.

Comment: So is there no point in testing if a class actually behaves like it should when there's no connection? I just wonder if it's possible, at all.
I can do the same if I use a stub with pre-made responses, but is it not possible at all with Mockito?

Comment: If you're testing `A`, the only things you need to test for `A` are whether or not it handles `B` properly if it provides a result, and if it throws an Exception. If you want to test `B` handling no connection, then you should not be mocking it.

Comment: Well, yeah, but B should throw an exception when there's no connection. So basically there's no way to do this with Mockito?

Comment: If you want to test whether `B.getData()` throws an exception, or a specific exception, where there's no connection, then you need to mock your connection in the tests for `B`, and check that the exception is thrown when your mock connection is down.  How to "mock your connection" will depend on what `B.getData()` does.  In any case, whether `B.getData()` throws or not, or what it throws, and under which circumstances, is not `A`'s concern, so it shouldn't be in `A`'s unit test.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, yeah, but B should throw an exception when there's no connection. So basically there's no way to do this with Mockito?

It is possible:

```
@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Mock B b;

@Test
public void getInfo_ExceptionThrownByB_ExceptionFallsThrough(){
   // prepare
   doThrow(new IOException("unitTest"))when(b).getData();
   A a = new A(b);
   // assert (before act because exceptions are special)
   exception.expect(IOException.class);
   exception.expectMessage("unitTest");
   // act 
   a.getInfo();
}
```

I think the major point is: be (yourself) clear about what you tests. Anything you test (which could be, but usually is not more than one class) *should not* be mocked. Anything that you code under tests interacts with *should* be mocked (unless that dependency is to simple to break like DTOs, or unlikely to change like JRE classes e.g.: collections).